# Hoch und tief mit Jahreszeiten

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Man sagt "Hochsommer" und "tiefster Winter".

- Warum nicht anders rum, oder beides gleich ("tiefster Sommer")
- Gab es früher mal andere Versionen?
- Wie sagt man für Frühling und Herbst?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"ES ist eben so" ist wahrscheinlich nicht das, was Du hören möchtest, aber es gibt für derartige Metaphern und Sprachfiguren eben nicht immer unbedingt eine logische Erklärung. "[Hochwinter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochwinter)" geht übrigens schon, mit -frühling und -herbst aber nicht, weil es sich hier um keine jahreszeitlichen Extreme handelt. Der Hochsommer ist die heißeste Zeit, der Hochwinter die kälteste Zeit des Jahres.

Es gibt aber auch für Frühlung und Herbst verstärkende und beschreibende Ausdrücke:

- Vorfrühling
- Erstfrühling
- Vollfrühling
- Frühsommer
- Hochsommer
- Spätsommer
- Frühherbst
- Vollherbst
- Spätherbst

Answer (score 4):

Hoch und tief beziehen sich möglicherweise auf den Sonnenstand in diesen Monaten, vielleicht auch, damit verbunden, die Temperaturen.

Für Frühling und Herbst gibt es keine "Positionsadjektive", nur allgemein auf das Wetter und die Umwelt allgemein bezogene beschreibende Adjektive.

> nass, mild, stürmisch

Hier sollte man auch die Farben der Jahreszeiten noch erwähnen:

- grüner Frühling
- Sommer N/A
- goldener Herbst
- weißer Winter

Comment: "goldener Sommer" > "goldener Herbst", wenn es um Google-Hits geht

Comment: und vermutlich "goldener Oktober" > "goldener Sommer".
Wenn er überhautpt irgendetwas ist, dann ist der Herbst "golden".

Answer (score 2):

Anders als heute war früher die Verwendung des Adjektivs *hoch* noch fest mit zeitlicher Bedeutung verknüpft <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH10156)</sup>. Davon gibt es noch heute Spuren:

> - Hochzeit
> - es ist höchste Zeit
> - hochschwanger sein

Zu diesen Überbleibseln gehört auch der **Hochsommer**, also die Zeit, in der der Sommer seinen Zenit erreicht.

Das Adjektiv *tief* war schon immer Antonym zu *hoch*, wenn auch nicht so sehr in zeitlicher Bedeutung, aber durchaus nicht nur in Bezug auf die vertikale Position, sondern auch um eine Intensität auszudrücken:

> - tief Singen
> - ein tief ergebener Untertan
> - tief im Herzen
> - in der tiefen Nacht

So wird *tief* (im Übrigen früher auch neben *"hoher Winter"*) als zeitliches Adjektiv zur Bestimmung der Mitte des Winters eingesetzt: **der tiefste Winter**. <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW22693)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Hier dürfte auch eine emotionale Konnotation mitspielen, wonach der warme Sommer angenehmer ist als der kalte Winter (selbst wenn allzu viel Hitze ja auch nicht das Gelbe vom Ei ist und umgekehrt mancher gerne Ski fährt). Man sagt ja auch eher, dass man "hoch erfreut" oder "zutiefst betrübt" ist. Andererseits stimmt diese Theorie wohl auch nicht 100%ig, den auch starke Dankbarkeit ist tief und nicht hoch (wohl weil aus dem tiefsten Inneren des Herzens kommend).

Answer (score 0):

Sommer kann "hoch" sein (im Sinne von Temperatur). Das Gegenteil ist "niedrig" und Winter kann "niedrig" sein.

Winter kann "tief" (im Sinne von Kälte) sein. Das Gegenteil ist "flach". Aber Sommer kann die Kälte betreffend **nicht** "flach" sein.

Deshalb können die Wörter für Sommer und Winter **nicht** entsprechen.

Comment: Man spricht zwar von einem Kältetief, aber Kälte ansich kann nicht "tief" sein. Und erst recht nicht "flach". Die Temperaturen sind aber "tief" – oder "niedrig", wie du es im ersten Absatz nennst. Spricht man doch mal von "tiefer Kälte", ist von "extremer Kälte" die Rede. Die haben wir in Deutschland aber für gewöhnlich nicht ;) Das Fazit versteh ich wohl nicht ganz. Der erste Paragraph stimmt. Btw: Im Deutschen werden Satzzeichen nicht von Anführungszeichen umfasst, daher habe ich das in meinem Edit geändert.